# Performing join given complex entity relationships in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-4.x

I'm having difficulty establishing an association between two entities in Hibernate.  The relationship is complicated.

We have a table (lets call it Translations) that contains translations used within our program whose primary key is the base text and the language code.  This means there are several lines with the same base text but with differing language codes.

```
Translations:
   BaseText
   LanguageCode
```

I have a second table (lets call it Usage) which indicates, for each distinct BaseText in Translations table, where it is used in the program.  The same text can be used in multiple places within the program, so there are potentially several lines with the same text but with differing programs.

```
Usage:
  Text
  Program
```

The one field that ties them both together is Text in Usage and BaseText in Translations.  If I wanted to write a query that selects translations pertaining to a specific Program (as indicated in Usage table), I would probably write something like:

```
select * from Translations inner join Usage on Translations.BaseText = Usage.Text where Usage.Program = ?
```

However, I'm using hibernate and JPA to do this.  I see many examples for creating a Parent-Child association between two entities, however this relationship is clearly a bit dysfunctional.  This would probably be better represented with a middle table and a many-to-many relationship, however to make things more complicated, this is a legacy program using a legacy database, and thus I can't really add any tables.

The closest question that I could find related to my problem I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2193756/hibernate-composite-primary-key-contains-a-composite-foreign-key-how-to-map-thi), however it deals with a much cleaner Parent-Child type relationship.  If I use only the one `JoinColumn`, it complains that the whole primary key is not satisfied.

Using annotations, how should I structure my entities so that I can optionally query Translation entities by Usage.program (if at least one line exists in Usage with a given program, I would like to retrieve its corresponding Translation line)?

This is what I have currently:

```
@Entity
public class Translation
    @Id
    private String baseText;

    @Id
    private String languageCode;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="baseText", referencedColumnName="text", nullable=false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Usage usage;

    // .. getters and setters
}

@Entity
public class Usage {
    @Id
    private String text;

    @Id 
    private String program;

    // .. getters and setters
    // OneToMany counterpart added, but I removed it because it seemed to
    // make Usage the "owner" entity of the relationship, which isn't my case
}
```

I appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: Hi! Have you found a solution to this? I am encountering a similar problem and have no clue how to proceed.