# Using Java Hibernate, how can you use nullable composite foreign keys when part of the composite key is part of your primary key?

Tags: java, sql-server, postgresql, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

Specifically with our database relationship being like so, title:

**Table S**

```
column id
...other irrelevant columns omitted...
primary key on id only
```

**Table C**

```
column S_id
column id
...
compound primary key on S_id (which is a foreign key to id column in table S) and id.
```

**Table I**

```
column S_id
column id
column C_id
...
compound primary key again on S_id and id.
compound foreign key on C_id and S_id, but C_id column in this table is also nullable.
```

I have attempted the following for java hibernate annotations on IObject for modeling table I:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumns({
    @JoinColumn({name="C_id", referencedColumnName="id",insertable=false,updateable=false),
    @JoinCOlumn({name="S_id", referencedColumnName="S_id", insertable=false,updateable=false)
})
private CObject _cObjectRef;
 
@EmbeddedId
private EmbeddedIdCompositeKeyObject _primaryKey;
...
```

Here is the important parts of java hibernate annotations on CObject for modeling table C:

```
@EmbeddedId
private EmbeddedIdCompositeKeyObject _primaryKey;
 
@MapsId("_s_id")
@ManyToOne(optional=false)
@JoinColumn(name="S_id", nullable = false)
private SObject _sObject;
...
```

And here is what EmbeddedIdCompositeKeyObject looks like (its @Embeddable and implements Serializable):

```
@Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
private int _id;
@Column(name = "S_id", nullable = false)
private int _s_id;

...
constructors, getters, hashCode, and equals ommitted.
```

However, when run, hibernate fails to update these columns of table I despite the _cObject being set to an existing CObject instance that matches what exists in the database. Every other column in the I object table saves and updates correctly upon calling hibernate's session.saveOrUpdate method on IObject except one where this nullable compound foreign key is used.

I have tried removing insertable and updateable qualifiers on the JoinColumns, or adding them in different combinations of true or false, and even mixing nullable in, however when that is attempted errors such as the following appear:

1. `Mixing nullable and non nullable columns in a property is not allowed` (this seems like what I need though)
2. `Mixing updatable and non updatable columns in a property is not allowed`
3. `Mixing insertable and non insertable columns in a property is not allowed`
4. `Repeated column in mapping for entity: foo.bar.IObject columns S_id (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false"`

Adding @MapsId("_s_id") to IObject's CObject reference doesn't appear to make a difference.

This question is somewhat similar to [another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32625410/hibernate-foreign-key-with-a-part-of-composite-primary-key) and almost exactly like [another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58516280/mapping-of-composite-primary-keys-and-foreign-keys-with-shared-columns-with-jpa?noredirect=1&lq=1), however neither questions appear to ask about cases with nullable composite foreign keys with primary key overlap, and none of the proposed solutions appear to work for this case, either.

Answer (score 0):

The quick answer is **you can't use nullable composite foreign keys in this way**.

With the help of a coworker however, we worked around the issue by changing perspective on the issue of tables owning portions of other tables, heres how for anyone else confused:

**Step 1:**
Create an @Embeddable style key class for any *1st derivative* tables (for example, the C table in the question, which *derives* its S_Id from the S table's int PK) like:

```
@Embeddeable
@Access(value = AccessType.FIELD)
public class S_IdAndIdPK implements Serializable
{
    private int id;
    private int S_id;
    ... {constuctors and method overrides ommitted}
}
```

NOTE: It is unnecessary to create an embeddable object for the table S's ID since its SEntity is already using a basic @ID of type INT.

This is the key for the *1st derivative* object.  Use this newly created key as the @EmbeddedId of table C when you define the entity for table C.  You can re-use this `S_IdAndIdPK` in any number of other tables which you would like to share this same database structure amongst.

**Step 2:**
Create an Embeddable object for the *2nd derivative* table that does not extend but rather INCLUDES AS A VARIABLE the @Embeddable style key class previously created in step 1.

**Step 3:**
Add `@AttributeOverride(name="id", column=@Column(name="my_col_new_name"))` above your variable.  This tells hibernate to use the database column called "my_col_new_name" instead of "id" but retains the fact that the original `S_IdAndIdPK` key object is *a part of* this "2nd derivative" entity's key which is needed to properly implement a @OneToMany mappedBy later.  To summarize in an example, steps 2 and 3 should look something like this:

```
@Embeddable
@Access(value = AccessType.FIELD)
public class S_IdC_IdAndIndexPK implements Serializable
{
    private int index;

    @AttributeOverride(name = "id", column = @Column(name="parent"))
    private S_IdAndIdPK parentPk;

    ... {constructors, getters and overrides omitted}
}
```

**Step 4:**
Now that the 1st derviative's key is properly included into the 2nd derivative's key, the 1st derivative entity may eager load via @OneToMany mappedBy relationships any 2nd derivative objects.

For example, if the entity DestinationEntity has its @EmbeddedID as `S_IdC_IdAndIndexPK`, CEntity may load all related Table I in the question (DestinationEntitys) when it is queried from the database:

```
@Entity
@Table(schema = "my_schema", name = "Cs")
@Access(value = AccessType.FIELD)
public class CEntity implements Serializable
{
    @OneToMany(
        cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
        fetch = FetchType.EAGER,
        mappedBy = "pk.parentPk", // look at DestinationEntity's pk.parentPk field to find which DestinationEntitys belong here
        orphanRemoval = true)
    @OrderBy("pk.index") // look at DestinationEntity's pk.index field to find order of objects that go into this array list
    private final List<DestinationEntity> destinations = new ArrayList<>();

    // Here is an example for a similar use case where instead
    //  of "index" a "name" column is used to 
    //  automatically populate a HashMap for this entity of 
    //  all its related Property (another derivative) objects.
    // Property entity would do the same as Destination for including its primary key but instead of index use string "name" as the column name
    @OneToMany(
        cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
        fetch = FetchType.EAGER,
        mappedBy = "pk.parentPk", // look at pk.parentPk field of PropertyEntity, which is this C_entity's pk to find related PropertyEntitys
        orphanRemoval = true)
    @MapKeyColumn(name = "name") // look to the PropertyEntity's "name" field when populating related PropertyEntitys into this map.
    private final Map<String, PropertyEntity> properties = new HashMap<>();

    @EmbeddedId
    private S_IdAndIdPK pk;

    ... {getters, setters, constructors, & overrides omitted}
}
```

The greatest advantage of this is the @Embeddable Pk's code is reusable for any other peer entity to 1st derivative objects, and each 2nd derivative only needs to override the attribute for the column name of "id" in the `1st derivative` Primary Key.  You can make there be any number of "id" foreign key fields for an object and it will not cause this concept to break when properly using @AttributeOverride.

You can then modify these CEntity Map and List data structures from POJO code, and when the parent object is done being changed and Hibernate save or update occurs, it will cascade all changes to any child *2nd derivative* objects that are modified from among these 2 example collections into their respective tables.  If any objects are removed from these collections, the orphanRemoval=true setting will cause them to automatically be deleted from their respective tables.

TL;DR:
Do not use 'extends' to extend any @EmbeddedId objects like `S_IdAndIdPk` by making something like an `S_IdC_IdAndIndexPk extends S_IdAndIdPk` because the id field may be re-appropriated in its purpose, and similarly do not use multiple @ID annotations either to bypass the fact that the object truly contains the key of another object.  Also don't try to query the database for 2nd derivative objects anywhere other than from the objects that own them such as in the question where I attempted to use @ManyToOne.  Instead make `S_IdAndIdPk` be @EmbeddedIds within any 2nd level derivative object's PKs such as `S_IdC_IdAndIndexPk` or `S_IdC_IdAndNamePk`, and use Attribute Overrides to map the original column names into your desired new column names in your 2nd derivative tables to avoid possible future collisions on the column name "id".

Hope this helps anyone else stuck on how to use Hibernate composite foreign keys properly for in-memory modeling of complex database relationships.